# Is there a way to alter ChildContent in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I'd like to alter ChildContent my component receives from the parent like this:

```
<Markdown>
  # Title

  Some _Content_
</Markdown>
```

To interpret this content I would need to do something like  *Markdown.ToHTML(@ChildContent)*.

But as *ChildContent* is not a string, I need some means to access the *ChildContent* and retrieve it as string. Is this possible and how can it be done? Any other idea to solve this?

Comment: Do you have some more code? What you mean with "alter ChildContent"? You want to replace the content from the Markdown?

Comment: @tire0011 ChildContent is a concept of Blazor that allows to pass content from the parent component to the child component. It's easy. Just declare a property of type RenderFragment and decorate it with the _[Parameter]_ attribute. But the problem is that I don't know how to get the content out of RenderFragment. But like in my example sometimes the content needs to be altered in some way before being displayed

Comment: maybe when you add more of your code it is better to understand?

Comment: @Daniel Schmid, unfortunately, you can't get the content out of the RenderFragment delegate, and you cannot access the Html elements embedded in this content.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't impossible but it's not a great way to go.

In order to take a render fragment and produce HTML, it needs to be run through a renderer. This isn't a particularly simple thing to achieve. If you want to see an example you can [look at the Test Renderer produced by Steve Sanderson](https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/BlazorUnitTestingPrototype/blob/master/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Testing/TestRenderer.cs) for his unit testing prototype.

You could have a go at creating your own renderer but I would suggesting considering a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have already found a solution, but take a look at the code snippet below (**.NET 5.0**):

```
var builder = new RenderTreeBuilder();
builder.AddContent(0, this.ChildContent);
var frame = builder.GetFrames().Array.FirstOrDefault(x => new[] 
{
  RenderTreeFrameType.Text, 
  RenderTreeFrameType.Markup 
}.Any(t => x.FrameType == t));
var value = frame?.MarkupContent;
```

Adding content to builder adds two frames, a region one and a text/markup one, depending on whether ChildContent contains plain text of HTML. Instead of guessing however, it is safer to use `FirstOrDefault`.

**NB:** This is kind of a hack and is not guaranteed that would work in future version of **Blazor**. I haven't used it with **Blazor 6.0** or **7.0** (in preview, yet to be released) but I am able to retrieve the content of, pardon me, `ChildContent`.